# right justify urdu fonts in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

How to right justify the Urdu fonts? Justify in Css make it left justify. Any trick? Thanks.

```
//--------- I have tried both method but both of them doesnt work with urdu font.
text-align:right;
text-align:justify;
```

Comment: provide a jsFiddle link to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use

```
direction:rtl
```